# Retrieve start date and end date of a JIRA sprint using the python JIRA library

Tags: jira, python-jira

Is there a way to get the start and end date of a sprint in JIRA using the python JIRA library? I can get a `jira.client.ResultList` with all the sprints within the board of interest using `jira.sprints(jira.boards()[<sequence number of the board of interest>].id)`. The list looks like this:

```
[<JIRA Sprint: name='LSD Sprint 1', id=1>,
...
<JIRA Sprint: name='LSD Sprint 14', id=14>]
```

Could I somehow access the start and end date for each sprint using something similar to `issue.fields` which returns me `jira.resources.PropertyHolder`, from which I can access additional data ?

Comment: I know this is for Python, but within `bash`, you can get it using this script: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60378905/1499296

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For testing I used `jirashell` (`python-jira 1.0.10`), `JIRA 6.3.11`, `JIRA 7.2.3`, `JIRA AGILE REST API v1.0`. I ran following code in `jirashell`:

```
dir(jira.sprints(jira.boards()[0].id)[0])
```

It prints all methods and attributes of the `sprint` object:

```
['AGILE_BASE_REST_PATH',
 'AGILE_BASE_URL',
 'AGILE_EXPERIMENTAL_REST_PATH',
 'GREENHOPPER_REST_PATH',
 'JIRA_BASE_URL',
 '_READABLE_IDS',
 '__class__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__dict__',
 '__doc__',
 '__format__',
 '__getattr__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__hash__',
 '__init__',
 '__module__',
 '__new__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__',
 '__weakref__',
 '_base_url',
 '_default_headers',
 '_get_url',
 '_load',
 '_options',
 '_parse_raw',
 '_resource',
 '_session',
 'delete',
 'find',
 'id',
 'linkedPagesCount',
 'name',
 'raw',
 'self',
 'sequence',
 'state',
 'update']
```

As you can see, the list does not contain `startDate` or `endDate` attributes. Nevertheless, quick googling for sprint [startDate and endDate properties via JIRA REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37429723/how-to-get-start-and-end-dates-of-a-sprint-using-jira-api) showed that API DOES support such properties. But it turned out that `python-jira` uses old version of JIRA AGILE REST API. For example, when I run `jira.sprints(jira.boards()[0].id)[0].self`, I get `https://[JIRA_URL]/rest/greenhopper/1.0/sprint/[ID]` as a result (not **agile/1.0** as mentioned in the answer where API supports startDate and endDate properties). Also `python-jira` throws a message `Old private GreenHopper API is used, all parameters will be ignored`.

So, I assume it is not possible to get `startDate` and `endDate` using `python-jira` due to old version of the JIRA AGILE API that it uses.

Comment: It's now possible to use the *agile* rest path as option:
`jira = JIRA("https://myjira.com", auth=(user, password), options={"agile_rest_path": GreenHopperResource.AGILE_BASE_REST_PATH})`

See `jira.resources.GreenHopperResource` for details.

Answer (score 2):

**Use sprint_info(board_id, sprint_id)**

This will return a dict of the sprint information. I wanted the date back as date formats, so I have some code that handles the conversion below and copes with the None values that are returned. Took ages to find this one, so thought a reply would be good as my first answer on Stack Overflow!!

```
    for board in boards:

        jira_sprints = jira.sprints(board.board_id)

        for jira_sprint in jira_sprints:

            sprint_info = jira.sprint_info(board.board_id, jira_sprint.id)

            board_id = board.board_id
            board_name = board.board_name
            name = sprint_info['name']
            id = sprint_info['id']


            if sprint_info['startDate'] != 'None':
                date_from = datetime.datetime.strptime(sprint_info['startDate'], "%d/%b/%y %I:%M %p").date()
            else:
                date_from = None
            if sprint_info['endDate'] != 'None':
                date_to = datetime.datetime.strptime(sprint_info['endDate'], "%d/%b/%y %I:%M %p").date()
            else:
                date_to = None
            state = sprint_info['state']
```

Answer (score 1):

Found a workaround for my issue, using the python `requests` library. Here is the link to it:
http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/

I used the following to get to the start and end date for the sprint of interest:

```
import requests
jiraResponse     = requests.get('https://<YOUR ATLASSIAN DOMAIN>.atlassian.net/rest/agile/1.0/board/<BOARD ID OF INTEREST>/sprint', auth=(<YOUR JIRA CREDENTIALS>))
jiraResponseJSON = jiraResponse.json()
```

`jiraResponseJSON` then is a dictionary whose `values`-key contains all the sprints contained in the board of interest within a list of objects, which themselves have the keys `'completeDate'`, `'endDate'`, and `'startDate'`.

`'endDate'` is obviously available before the sprint is actually closed, whereas `'completeDate'` becomes available only when the sprint gets closed, e.g. its status changes from `active` to `closed`.

Examples for what I used:

```
startDate = jiraResponseJSON['values'][<SPRINT NUMBER>]['startDate'][:10]
endDate   = jiraResponseJSON['values'][<SPRINT NUMBER>]['completeDate'][:10]
```

Having found the start and end date for a sprint, one could then further use both of them as variables in a python-jira query such as:

`jira.search_issues('project=<YOUR PROJECT NAME> and issuetype=bug AND status changed to closed DURING ("' + startDate + '", "' + endDate + '")', maxResults=100)`